# Area between two curves (Demidovich)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve some problems on definite integrals from Demidovich's book and I'm stuck on calculating the area between two curves defined by:
$$y_1 = \frac{a^3}{a^2 + x^2}, y_2 = 0$$

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you do the case where $a=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $a>0$. You are asked to evaluate something like
$$
\int_0^M\frac{a^3}{a^2+x^2}dx,
$$ then performing the change of variable $x=a\tan u$ gives
$$
\int_0^M\frac{a^3}{a^2+x^2}dx=\int_0^{\arctan (M/a)}\frac{a^3}{a^2\color{red}{(1+\tan^2u)}}\cdot a\cdot \color{red}{(1+\tan^2u)}\:du=a^2\arctan \left( \frac{M}a\right).
$$

Comment: Err... Rather, from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?  And do you need to be careful with signs, when $a$ is negative?

Comment: @mathguy Observe that since the integrand is an even function, we get that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty=2\int_0^\infty=2\lim_{M\to \infty}\int_0^M$.